# Symfony messenger:consume not working (no exception)

Tags: symfony

`Symfony 5.1`

I'm trying to setup an async email handler for my project. Emails are sended into Doctrine messenger_messages table but when I use the command `php bin/console messenger:consume -vv`, I have the `[OK] Consuming messages from transports "async".` message in console, but no message in the table is delivered.

Edit : It worked yesterday and it didn't worked when I tried again today. I restarted my server while the consumer was running and in the error message :

```
An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT m.* FROM messenger_messages m WHERE (m.delivered_at is null
  OR m.delivered_at < ?) AND (m.available_at <= ?) AND (m.queue_name = ?) ORDER BY available_at ASC LIMIT 1
  FOR UPDATE' with params ["2020-07-16 07:20:55", "2020-07-16 08:20:55", "default"]:

  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away
```

I saw that the consumer check 'available_at <= 2020-07-16 08:20:55' while the older message in my table is available_at 2020-07-16 09:33:30. I don't know how to change that.

Edit2 : It looks like I have a timezone problem : My timezone is UTC+2 and it's 10:36 right now, but in the dev.log, the consumer is doing request for 08:36 :

```
[2020-07-16T08:36:44.241767+00:00] doctrine.DEBUG: "COMMIT" [] []
[2020-07-16T08:36:45.242051+00:00] doctrine.DEBUG: "START TRANSACTION" [] []
[2020-07-16T08:36:45.242341+00:00] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT m.* FROM messenger_messages m WHERE (m.delivered_at is null OR m.delivered_at < ?) AND (m.available_at <= ?) AND (m.queue_name = ?) ORDER BY available_at ASC LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE ["2020-07-16T07:36:45+00:00","2020-07-16T08:36:45+00:00","default"] []
```

Edit3 : My problem was in the php.ini used by the CLI. I had defined my timezone in the php.ini used by Symfony but not in the CLI one, so since the consumer is ran from the console, it was at UTC and not UTC+2.

My EmailHandler :

```
class EmailHandler implements MessageHandlerInterface
{
    private $address;
    private $mailer;

    public function __construct($address, MailerInterface $mailer)
    {
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
        $this->address = $address;
    }
    public function __invoke(Email $email)
    {
        $user =  $email->getTask()->getIdUser();
        $token = $user->getToken();
        $email = (new TemplatedEmail())
            ->from($this->address)
            ->to($user->getEmail())
            ->subject('Activation de compte Classe Virtuelle')
            ->htmlTemplate('emails/activate.html.twig')
            ->context([
                'address' => $user->getEmail(),
                'nom' => $email->getTask()->getNom(),
                'prenom' => $email->getTask()->getPrenom(),
                'token' => $token
            ]);
            $this->mailer->send($email);
    }
```

My Email:

```
class Email
{
    private $task;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getTask()
    {
        return $this->task;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $task
     */
    public function setTask($task): void
    {
        $this->task = $task;
    }
}
```

messenger.yaml

```
    framework:
    messenger:
        # Uncomment this (and the failed transport below) to send failed messages to this transport for later handling.
        # failure_transport: failed

        transports:
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html#transport-configuration
            async: '%env(MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN)%'
            # failed: 'doctrine://default?queue_name=failed'
            # sync: 'sync://'

        routing:
            # Route your messages to the transports
            'App\Controller\Message\Email': async
```

.env

```
MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN=doctrine://default
```

my controller

```
            $email = new Email();
            $email->setTask($addUser);
            $messageBus->dispatch($email);
```

a line added in my table when I dispatch an email in my controller

```
100,
"O:36:\""Symfony\\Component\\Messenger\\Envelope\"":2:{s:44:\""\0Symfony\\Component\\Messenger\\Envelope\0stamps\"";a:1:{s:46:\""Symfony\\Component\\Messenger\\Stamp\\BusNameStamp\"";a:1:{i:0;O:46:\""Symfony\\Component\\Messenger\\Stamp\\BusNameStamp\"":1:{s:55:\""\0Symfony\\Component\\Messenger\\Stamp\\BusNameStamp\0busName\"";s:21:\""messenger.bus.default\"";}}}s:45:\""\0Symfony\\Component\\Messenger\\Envelope\0message\"";O:28:\""App\\Controller\\Message\\Email\"":1:{s:34:\""\0App\\Controller\\Message\\Email\0task\"";O:17:\""App\\Entity\\Eleves\"":7:{s:21:\""\0App\\Entity\\Eleves\0id\"";N;s:26:\""\0App\\Entity\\Eleves\0id_user\"";O:16:\""App\\Entity\\Users\"":12:{s:20:\""\0App\\Entity\\Users\0id\"";N;s:29:\""\0App\\Entity\\Users\0identifiant\"";s:40:\""200c6d84e5eeeec42b1c7ea1ff2945340013f5db\"";s:21:\""\0App\\Entity\\Users\0mdp\"";s:40:\""f0f1b73b43acb236eb1388bd781189209361b8b2\"";s:23:\""\0App\\Entity\\Users\0email\"";s:20:\""zedzdezde@zedzde.zed\"";s:25:\""\0App\\Entity\\Users\0id_role\"";O:16:\""App\\Entity\\Roles\"":3:{s:20:\""\0App\\Entity\\Roles\0id\"";i:1;s:26:\""\0App\\Entity\\Roles\0nom_role\"";s:10:\""ROLE_ELEVE\"";s:23:\""\0App\\Entity\\Roles\0users\"";O:33:\""Doctrine\\ORM\\PersistentCollection\"":2:{s:13:\""\0*\0collection\"";O:43:\""Doctrine\\Common\\Collections\\ArrayCollection\"":1:{s:53:\""\0Doctrine\\Common\\Collections\\ArrayCollection\0elements\"";a:0:{}}s:14:\""\0*\0initialized\"";b:0;}}s:40:\""\0App\\Entity\\Users\0commentaires_concernes\"";O:43:\""Doctrine\\Common\\Collections\\ArrayCollection\"":1:{s:53:\""\0Doctrine\\Common\\Collections\\ArrayCollection\0elements\"";a:0:{}}s:37:\""\0App\\Entity\\Users\0commentaires_ecrits\"";O:43:\""Doctrine\\Common\\Collections\\ArrayCollection\"":1:{s:53:\""\0Doctrine\\Common\\Collections\\ArrayCollection\0elements\"";a:0:{}}s:29:\""\0App\\Entity\\Users\0sousgroupes\"";O:43:\""Doctrine\\Common\\Collections\\ArrayCollection\"":1:{s:53:\""\0Doctrine\\Common\\Collections\\ArrayCollection\0elements\"";a:0:{}}s:23:\""\0App\\Entity\\Users\0actif\"";i:0;s:24:\""\0App\\Entity\\Users\0admins\"";N;s:38:\""\0App\\Entity\\Users\0sousgroupes_visibles\"";O:43:\""Doctrine\\Common\\Collections\\ArrayCollection\"":1:{s:53:\""\0Doctrine\\Common\\Collections\\ArrayCollection\0elements\"";a:0:{}}s:23:\""\0App\\Entity\\Users\0token\"";s:40:\""f3ab58732b9bf1029f3105f65d2469fd955e61b6\"";}s:22:\""\0App\\Entity\\Eleves\0nom\"";s:7:\""aezdzed\"";s:25:\""\0App\\Entity\\Eleves\0prenom\"";s:9:\""zedzdezed\"";s:28:\""\0App\\Entity\\Eleves\0id_classe\"";O:18:\""App\\Entity\\Classes\"":6:{s:22:\""\0App\\Entity\\Classes\0id\"";i:1;s:30:\""\0App\\Entity\\Classes\0nom_classe\"";s:5:\""2nde1\"";s:26:\""\0App\\Entity\\Classes\0eleves\"";O:33:\""Doctrine\\ORM\\PersistentCollection\"":2:{s:13:\""\0*\0collection\"";O:43:\""Doctrine\\Common\\Collections\\ArrayCollection\"":1:{s:53:\""\0Doctrine\\Common\\Collections\\ArrayCollection\0elements\"";a:0:{}}s:14:\""\0*\0initialized\"";b:0;}s:25:\""\0App\\Entity\\Classes\0cours\"";O:33:\""Doctrine\\ORM\\PersistentCollection\"":2:{s:13:\""\0*\0collection\"";O:43:\""Doctrine\\Common\\Collections\\ArrayCollection\"":1:{s:53:\""\0Doctrine\\Common\\Collections\\ArrayCollection\0elements\"";a:0:{}}s:14:\""\0*\0initialized\"";b:0;}s:28:\""\0App\\Entity\\Classes\0archives\"";O:33:\""Doctrine\\ORM\\PersistentCollection\"":2:{s:13:\""\0*\0collection\"";O:43:\""Doctrine\\Common\\Collections\\ArrayCollection\"":1:{s:53:\""\0Doctrine\\Common\\Collections\\ArrayCollection\0elements\"";a:0:{}}s:14:\""\0*\0initialized\"";b:0;}s:25:\""\0App\\Entity\\Classes\0profs\"";O:33:\""Doctrine\\ORM\\PersistentCollection\"":2:{s:13:\""\0*\0collection\"";O:43:\""Doctrine\\Common\\Collections\\ArrayCollection\"":1:{s:53:\""\0Doctrine\\Common\\Collections\\ArrayCollection\0elements\"";a:0:{}}s:14:\""\0*\0initialized\"";b:0;}}s:32:\""\0App\\Entity\\Eleves\0id_sousgroupe\"";O:43:\""Doctrine\\Common\\Collections\\ArrayCollection\"":1:{s:53:\""\0Doctrine\\Common\\Collections\\ArrayCollection\0elements\"";a:0:{}}s:23:\""\0App\\Entity\\Eleves\0type\"";s:6:\""Eleves\"";}}}",
[],
default,
2020-07-15 16:05:25,
2020-07-15 16:05:25,
```

Comment: have you looked into the database what the messenger_messages table contains? and if things are added when you *don't* have the consumer running?

Comment: When the consuper is not running, massages are added in the table and I paste the line added in the table

Comment: so ... it actually consumes messages. which means, the mailer isn't working properly. Have you tried - instead of using the message bus to just send an email with the mailer?

Comment: I used this mailer successfully before trying to setup messenger, but it was in a simple service. If I understand correctly what you're saying, the problem is in my EmailHandler class

Comment: if storing emails into the queue works, then yeah, tht would be the logical conclusion. can you do some debug output for the handler? have you checked the var/log/....log files for output?

Comment: When I instance EmailHandler with a dummy address and a MailerInterface before invoke it with an Email instance as parameter, it works fine : I receive an email with my dummy address as the sender. However, i remember something : i ran php bin/console messenger:setup-transports to try and it sent the first message in the table when I launched the consumer. Edit : I just reran setup-transport and now, looks like it works fine

Answer (score 6):

Check if you configured the right timezone in php.ini. Worker pick and execute queued tasks by created_at and available_at db columns.
As I see in your provided log data your PHP timezone set to UTC which is probably not intended.

log:

```
[2020-07-16T08:36:45.242341+00:00] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT m.* FROM messenger_messages m WHERE (m.delivered_at is null OR m.delivered_at < ?) AND (m.available_at <= ?) AND (m.queue_name = ?) ORDER BY available_at ASC LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE ["2020-07-16T07:36:45+00:00","2020-07-16T08:36:45+00:00","default"] []
```

db:

```
2020-07-15 16:05:25,
2020-07-15 16:05:25,
```

As you see message queued for 7:30 hours later.

Set proper timezone in php.ini from https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php and restart the service.

if you have no idea where the php.ini located run this command:

```
php -i | grep php.ini
```

Comment: Exactly this - my timezone was New Zealand for PHP. It should have been UTC.  Restarted my messenger service after changing it and created new jobs.

Comment: In my case, timezone in fpm/php.ini and cli/php.ini should have the same value...